# New users treatment: a case study

Tags: discussion, new-users, humor

Recent moderator elections pays a lot of attention to how to green a new user on SO. Here is an example how a misleading produces offtopic funny answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868644/how-to-separate-values

Can current moderators, please, elaborate on what should be done in this particular case? How we can help the new user to feel satisfied and not offended with SO?

Comment: We can't make everyone satisfied. If someone will barge in and ask "what color is your fish?" we can also post funny answers, but it probably won't satisfy him. Same case here, he did not post any real question thus can't really get a real answer. "unclear what you're asking" is as clear a message as one can hope for.

Comment: Reading the comment chain, it looks like the sarcastic actually got the attention of the OP and looks like he was satisfied with the final response since it is marked as an answer.  No harm, no foul in my opinion.

Comment: I'm more offended by the author of the answer asking to accept his answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003: that was a 100k+ user...

Comment: I cast my delete vote...

Comment: @SergeyK. yeah, I know, but doesn't change my opinion.  The actual answer seemed to be ok, asking for an accept is not.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I'm not arguing with you. Your comment just keeps up with my own opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that in the future, it's best to direct OP to "How to Ask" and ask for clarification when we notice that he is unsure on how to use the site. This is what's done in most cases (at least in tags I watch).

I'd say this is far from a 'positive example for the community' but I think it was reasonable since:

- The high reputation user ended up helping the OP with the problem, OP took it positively and it ended well with OP learning about the problem and the solution.
- Niet was not mocking him personally, and his joke wasn't in 'poor taste'
- He did [admit it's not a model answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868644/how-to-separate-values#comment33109436_21868662) and he probably didn't expect much from it.
- It is a very low profile question. You don't even have to read it all to see that it's not fresh from the top of the month list.

All in all, Niet's joke ended up working pretty well. Had it not ended up pretty well - this answer would of course be very different. This is a risk you take when you post these sort of answers. Had OP not cooperated or taken it well it would've left a very negative impression.

"Fun and Games" are generally 'bar' in Q&A sites and at the very best they are a gamble - this time it paid off, I'm not sure about the next.

Comment: I also like to note I agree with @psubsee2003 that asking for an accept is very poor manners - even more so with new users. There are more mannered ways to teach OP about accepting answers (For example - by directing him towards meta and asking him to consider accepting _a_ answer _if_ his problem is fixed _when_ he feels the issue is resolved)

Comment: "by directing him towards meta" - that's a very good point, btw. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Namely [the "How does accepting an answer work" link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is good since it includes well written passages on "Which answer should I choose?" and on "What should I do if none of the answers is suitable?"